# Finding the direction in which the camera faces

Tags: aframe

I am able to get the current position the camera is in, i.e, its x,y,z co-ordinates in aframe.

In the below code, I am making my camera move forward.

```
function move_camera_forward(){
x=$("#cam").attr("position").x;
y=$("#cam").attr("position").y;
z=$("#cam").attr("position").z;
updated_pos=x+" "+y+" "+String(Number(z)-0.2);
$("#cam").attr("position",updated_pos);
}
```

But this moves the camera along z axis irrespective the direction the camera is facing. I want to move the camera based on the direction faced by the camera. If the camera is facing lets say 45 degrees, I want to update the three co-ordinates. For this I need to find out in which direction the camera is facing. How can I do this? Does it have something to do with fov?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this. camera has a rotation attribute which gives me the angle of rotation. With this data and a bit of trigonometry, we can find the updated position. The below code moves the camera in the direction in which the user sees.

```
    new_x = 0;
    new_z = 0;
    function move_camera_forward() {
        x = $("#cam").attr("position").x;
        y = $("#cam").attr("position").y;
        z = $("#cam").attr("position").z;
        radian = -($("#cam").attr("rotation").y) * (Math.PI / 180);
        new_z = (new_z + (0.1 * Math.cos(radian)));
        new_x = new_x + (0.1 * Math.sin(radian));
        new_pos = new_x + " " + y + " " + (-new_z);
        console.log(new_pos)
        $("#cam").attr("position", new_pos)

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dive into the Three.js API to get any additional info that Aframe doesn't necessarily bubble to the surface. So you can get the camera object using

`var camera = document.querySelector('[camera]').object3D`

and then you have access to all the Vector data for the camera. To get the direction the camera is facing you can use `camera.getWorldDirection()` and that returns a Vector3 with X,Y and Z values.